# Equivalent of chmod +x in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, file-permissions, ruby-1.8.7

In Linux, it is very easy "just" to add executable to a file, simply by input:

```
chmod +x <fname>
```

However, I have failed to find something as easy in the gems of Ruby. Of course, one could do a system call, i.e.

```
system( 'chmod +x' << fname )
```

However, I am looking for something more 'elegant'.

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Perhaps this would be useful: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-chmod

Comment: Indeed it does. Unfortunately, I was having a search options to the Ruby 1.8.7, which does not have it... Well, 2 issues resolved for the price on 1...

Comment: Oh - I see... It might be a good idea to include the ruby version you are working with (especially if it is one of your limitations)

Comment: From [Ruby 1.8.7 documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-chmod): `FileUtils.chmod 0644, '/my/directory/which/contains/my/file'`.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I know the "other permissions", that is, I do not want to change write/read permissions. I could read them in, and bitwise them, I guess...

Comment: The "symbolic mode" syntax (`+x` etc.) is a feature of the `chmod(1)` utility. AFAIK no programming language supports that. You'll need to write a wrapper around `FileUtils.chmod`, or (better) just use octal permissions ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the current mode using `File.stat` and then bitwise '''or''' it with a mask to achieve what you want. Here is a sample (which could be shortened):

`current_mask = File.stat('foo.sh').mode
new_mask = current_mask | '0000000000000001'.to_i(2)
File.chmod(new_mask, 'foo.sh')`

Answer (score 16):

```
require "fileutils"

FileUtils.chmod("+x", "foo.sh")
```